# Cache contains data, but can't retrieve data

Tags: c#, .net, caching

Here's my bit of code:

```
List<Sale> sales = new List<Sale>();

if (Cache["Sales"] != null)
{
    sales = (List<Sale>)Cache["Sales"];
}
else
{
    ...
    Cache.Add("Sales", sales, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20),
        Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
}
```

When I try to pull the data from the cache, my "sales" object is null. Wondering why that code is hit at all, I ran the debugger in VS to see what was in the Cache object.

The Cache contains the data I need, but when it gets the data from cache, "sales" still comes out as null.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

I'm getting this error on casting:

> [A]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[controls_mySales+Sale] cannot be cast to [B]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[controls_mySales+Sale]. Type A originates from 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Type B originates from 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'

Comment: Is that the only place in your codebase where you assign a value to that cache key?

Comment: Have you tried doing a cast to `List<Sale>` as opposed to using the `as` operator?  Perhaps there's a casting issue.

Comment: What happens if you store a `Sale` instead of a `List<Sale>`? What casting error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN's page on the [`as` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(v=VS.71).aspx) states that:

> The **as** operator is like a cast
>   except that it yields null on
>   conversion failure instead of raising
>   an exception.

Looks this is what's happening here -- the cast to type `List<Sale>` is failing, and returning `null`. Are you sure this is the type of the object in your cache?

**EDIT:**

In response to your edit, it seems like some sort of assembly-related serialization/deserialization issue possible related to [binding contexts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx) that honestly is a little over my head. I checked around and found the following two questions here on SO that may be able to point you in the right direction:

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838568/error-rendering-control-a-cannot-be-cast-to-b-in-the-context-loadneither)
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141787/invalidcastexception-when-serializing-and-deserializing)

Hopefully those links prove helpful.

Comment: Nice research. I've edited my original post showing the exception being thrown. Do you know what's wrong with that?

Comment: This is a known issue, for more http://www.dotshoppingcart.com/View/Forum/DotShoppingCart%20Forums/Support/Using%20DotShoppingCart/369.aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dotshoppingcart.com/View/Forum/DotShoppingCart%20Forums/Support/Using%20DotShoppingCart/369.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously two classes `Sale`.

It looks like a nested class in a dynamically compiled Page or UserControl.  Difficult to understand exactly what's going on without seeing more code, but perhaps when the Page/UserControl is recompiled for some reason, it gets a new type.

I'd move the `Sale` class out into its own non-nested class in its own source file.